# Clear Cookies and Session data when user logs out from Django web app when using built-in logout url

Tags: jquery, django, cookies

I am having a problem with me Django web application. Every now and then I get

```
Request Header Or Cookie Too Large
```

nginx error message when I get the site. This is solved by me deleting cookies in inspect element > application > cookies > clear.

Obviously I dont want nor expect users of the app to do that whenever this issue pops up.

I am using the built-in logout url in the template of my Django application:

```
<a href="{% url 'logout' %}">Log Out</a>
```

And I want to clear the cookies created including some session data I added before when a user logs out.

Session data added like :

```
session = request.session
session['claim'] = a_url
```

Whether from within Django or using some onclick jquery event in the template that's fine.

I prefer it to be done from Django as then I can also clear the cookies if a logged out users requets the page (as a user might simply close the app without logging in). If a logout function (ie path) needs to be created to clear cookies, then please include that in your answer. But JQuery is fine as well.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can directly `request.sesion['claim'] = a_url` without assignment.

Comment: @AmineMessaoudi I use session many times throughout my code. Assignment helps reduce the amount of code I would have to write.